# Is there a way to have strong type check in React-Admin resources?

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I'm trying to strong type all datas handled by ReactAdmin in my project.

ReactAdmin seems to handle all its data as instances of Record :

```
export interface Record {
    id: Identifier;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

which basically tells Typescript to stop the type-check on whatever object is a Record. The issue is that ALL objects in React-Admin are Records.

Is there a way to declare a type for each resources? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you write your queries using the specialized react-admin hooks, you can pass a type:

```
const { data, error, loaded } = useGetOne<Product>('products', 123);
          |
          -- TypeScript sees data as a value of type Product
```

The only requirement is that the type you pass (`Product` in this example) extends react-admin's `Record` type, which only forces your records to have an `id` field.

The react-admin documentation is lacking on that front, but pay attention to the types shown by your IDE, they show generic hooks:

[image]